# select rows that have no null values

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

in an sql database I need a script that will select all the rows that has no null value something like this:

```
For all the rows in the database
     if row has no null values
         select it
```

Columns are dynamic, I cannot know their number or names

Thanks you

Comment: Did you mean a specific table? or the whole database? What kind of "dynamic" are you talking about. Temp tables included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the opposite of this question [Test if any fields are NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null/14870#14870).

The answer by [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith) modified to find rows without null values would look like this.

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select *
from YourTable as T
where
  (
    select T.*
    for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type 
  ).exist('//*/@ns:nil') = 0
```

And the answer provided by [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) modified would be...

```
DECLARE @tb NVARCHAR(255) = N'YourTable';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tb
    + ' WHERE 1 = 1';

SELECT @sql += N' AND ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' IS NOT NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tb);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score -1):

Approach:

- Get column names of a table from sys.columns
- do the select with multiple WHERE conditions ANDed: WHERE ColA IS NOT NULL AND ColB IS NOT NULL and so on...